# populating popover bootstrap with calling a webservice

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to populate the popover (from bootstrap) with a webservice which is called by AJAX.

I tried:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myURL?action=fetchData&ID=123",
    success: function(msg) {
        $('.key_cal').popover({
            title:"User Profile",
            placement:'right',
            content:"<h5>Name: "+msg[0].firstName+"</h5>",
            html: true
        });
    }
});
```

But I need to call AJAX inside the popover to populate the content, but I have no clue; could you please help me?

Now instead of hardcoding ID in my url (AJAX) with 123 I want to use the id of element which is clicked for popover. (I have passed the id of each element as a key)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your JavaScript is incomplete and poorly formatted.  Can you show it more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.key_cal').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = this.id;
    var $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myURL?action=fetchData&ID=" + id
    }).done(function (msg) {
        $this.popover({
            title: 'myTitle',
            content: function () {
                return "<h5>Name: " + msg[0].firstName + "</h5>";
            },
            html: true
        }).popover('show');
    });
});
```

Hope this helps, but i'm not sure why you are sending data over URL (query string) for `POST` request? Instead you can specify it as `data` object of the ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give each key-cal or whatever class you are using the popover, not fire the popover on AJAX.

```
$(document).ready() {
    $(".key-cal").hover(setPopover);
}

function setPopover() {
        var myTitle = "";
        var myContent = "";
        var myHtml = true;
        $.ajax({
            //  Go grab your data
            data: 'id=' + $(this).prop('id'),
            success: //Set your variables
        });
        $(this).popover({
            title: myTitle,
            content: myContent,
            html: true
        }).popover('show');
    }, function () {
        $(this).popover('hide');
    });
}
```

This isn't the best or most efficient way, but it should make decent sense to you and allow you to go from there.  Fire the popover ajax call on hover, set the data, and then show the popover.